# Handling of selectedvalue when both options are chosen

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a dynamic chart tile when using drill-down.  One of my slicers looks like this:

[image]

Here is my DAX formula for creating the snippet of the chart title:

```
var Standard = if(
isfiltered(yrs_data[Standard]),
    if(exact(SELECTEDVALUE(yrs_data[Standard]),"Yes"),
        "LOT TYPE=PROD",
        "LOT TYPE=ENG"
    ),
"LOT TYPE=ALL"
)
```

The chart title works correctly except when both 'Yes' and 'No' are selected, then it incorrectly chooses "LOT TYPE=ENG", where I want it to be "LOT TYPE=ALL".

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this

```
test =
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( yrs_data[Standard] ),
    IF (
        EXACT ( SELECTEDVALUE ( yrs_data[Standard] ), "Yes" ),
        "LOT TYPE=PROD",
        IF (
            EXACT ( SELECTEDVALUE ( yrs_data[Standard] ), "No" ),
            "LOT TYPE=ENG",
            "LOT TYPE=ALL"
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thx for the help @smpa01